# drush devel-reinstall does not rebuild tables

Tags: 7, drush

For some reason if a module is a dependency other another module, and I run 'drush devel-reinstall' on it, it does not delete and then rebuild the tables for that module.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently because the module can't be uninstalled because another one is dependent on it.